# ORA-00001: unique constraint (TEST.SALES_PK) violated

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm trying to to make an insert into Database and I see this message on the logs:

```
OCI0000179 - Error - ORA-00001: unique constraint (TEST.SALES_PK) violated
```

I found this query to get the violated key:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_name FROM ALL_INDEXES WHERE INDEX_NAME='SALES_PK';
```

But is returning nothing. Anyone knows how to get the field this error message come from?

Regards

Edit:

Return nothing, even witk 'like' or wildcard

Comment: Try using `LIKE` with wildcards instead of `=`.

Comment: I tryed and returns nothing

Comment: and wildcards (%)  I suppose.

Comment: ALL_INDEXES is in the SYS schema. You might need privileges to get results from that query. Log AS SYSDBA with proper credentials to run that query.

Comment: I also tryed with SYSDBA user and still returning nothing

Comment: The index might have a SYS_XXXXX name, that name belongs to the constraint (PK). Check the index name associated to that constraint.

Comment: @Alfabravo since the all_* views show objects the logged in schema owns and has privileges against. Therefore you don't need special privileges to access the all_* views. You might, however, if you wanted to select against the equivalent dba_* views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

With this query I found the index_name:

```
select * from dba_constraints where constraint_name = 'SALES_PK'
```

And with this I found the table name:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_name FROM ALL_INDEXES WHERE INDEX_NAME='SALES_PK';
```

Thanks to @Boneist

Answer (score 3):

Probably should look at the constraint in question first.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS
 WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'SALES_PK'
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_1037.htm#sthref1152

Comment: returns nothing also

Comment: @ptercat - check edit for the contraint view.  -- you might have to play around with what filter to use -- or just look at all of them till you find it.

Comment: @ptercat what if you run the equivalent query against dba_constraints - e.g. `select * from dba_constraints where constraint_name = 'SALES_PK';`?